# What language do Kapacitor's alert message templates use?

Tags: kapacitor, chronograf

When I send an alert through Kapacitor, either by [defining one directly in TICKscript](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.3/nodes/alert_node/#message) or by [configuring one in Chronograf](https://docs.influxdata.com/chronograf/v1.3/guides/create-a-kapacitor-alert/), I get to specify a *Message* using a template syntax. However, this syntax isn't documented in any great detail at https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.3/nodes/alert_node/#message; instead, the docs just provide a few examples.

What language are these templates even written in? Does the language have a name? Any documentation? How does its syntax work, and what can I do with it besides simply template in the variables listed in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since Kapacitor is written in Golang, it would be safe to assume that that are Golang templates, and they are indeed, as we could [see in sourcecode](https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/blob/ea9612a26271bc9ed45e1dbe3d188e41337e05c1/alert.go#L65).

What else you could do besides just embedding variables? Well, lots of stuff, check the documentation: https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/

For example, iterate over tags:

```
{{ range $tag_key, $tag_value := .Tags}} {{$tag_key}}={{$tag_value}} {{end}}
```

Comment: Hi, can you help me with this. Alert format - "{"time":"2022-08-24T06:00:00Z","duration":0,"level":"OK","data":{"series":[{"name":"kpi","tags":{"BID":"1017","_field":"key-field","cid":"labec17-1017","version":"6.0"},"columns":["time","_value"],"values":[["2022-08-24T06:00:00Z","100"]]}]},"previousLevel":"CRITICAL","recoverable":true}" . I want to remove time from "columns" array and similarily timestamp from "values" array. How can I do it?